# If $p : E \to X$ is a covering map and $E$ is path connected, then all the fibers have the same cardinality.

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness, covering-spaces, path-connected

Let $p:E \rightarrow X$ be a covering space.

*It is well known that if $X$ is connected, then all the fibers have the same cardinality. This can be seen as a simple consequence of the fact that the cardinality of $p^{-1}(x)$ is a locally constant map.*

My question is, assuming **$E$** is path-connected, how can I prove that all the fibers have the same cardinality? Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

**-- EDIT --**

*Idea* : If $E$ is path connected, then $X$ is connected and we're done. To see that $X$ is connected, let $x,y\in X$ and let $x_{0}\in p^{-1}(x)$ and $y_{0}\in p^{-1}(y)$. Since $E$ is path connected, let $\sigma$ be a path connecting $x_{0}$ to $y_{0}$. Then, $p\circ\sigma$ is a path connecting $x$ to $y$. Thus, $X$ is path connected and hence, connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another way you can say this by using **uniqueness of path-lifting**

given two points $x$ & $y \in X$ you can consider a path from $x$ to $y$ (this will exists since $E$ is path-connected and $p$ is continuous)...then given any point $x_0 \in p^{-1} (x)$ you can get a lift of that path starting from $x_0$ ...and by the uniqueness there will be a unique $y_0$ where the lift of the initial path will end..this gives a injective map from the set $p^{-1}(x) \to P^{-1} (y) $ ...and by using same argument we'll get a injective map  $p^{-1}(y) \to P^{-1} (x) $ ...this will prove that all the fibers have same cardinality.

(but honestly speaking some how in this proof also I am using the fact that $p$ is locally homeomorphism...so this proof is not very far away from the proof you've mentioned)

Comment: If I prove that $X$ is connected, it's done. So, let $x,y\in X$. Consider $x_{0}\in p^{-1}(x)$ and $y_{0}\in p^{-1}(y)$. Since $E$ is by hypothesis path connected, let $\sigma$ be a path connecting $x_{0}$ and $y_{0}$. Then, $p\circ\sigma$ is a path connecting $x$ and $y$. Thus, $X$ is connected. Is there something missing ?

Comment: it is all right..but more over observe $p$ is continuous...and continuous image of a path-connected space is path-connected.

Comment: thanks for a "different" approach, though :)