# Why are the fibers of a covering map are homeomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $E$ and $X$ are topological spaces and $p:E \rightarrow X$ be a covering map. Whys are all the fibers homeomorphic?

Comment: In you definition of covering, is $X$ connected ?

Comment: Let's assume it is arc-wise connected.

Comment: A standard argument (works e.g. also for the dimension of a manifold) is that the continous assignment $x\in X \mapsto \#p^{-1}(x)$ is locally constant. Hence it is constant on connected components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're not necessarily; you need to assume $X$ is connected.

If $X$ is connected, consider the equivalence relation given by $x \sim y$ if $f^{-1}(x)$ is homeomorphic to $f^{-1}(y)$. (For covering maps, this is the same as the equivalence relation given by saying that $|f^{-1}(x)| = |f^{-1}(y)|$.) Show that equivalence classes are open using the definition of a covering space. Now if there is more than one equivalence class, you can use these to write $X$ as a disjoint union of nonempty open sets; contradiction, since we assumed $X$ connected.

Answer (score 1):

if we assume $X$ is connected then basically fiber of a single point is a discrete set...and fiber of two distinct point have  same cardinality ... so any bijection is actually a homeomorphism.

Comment: Why will it have same cardinality if X is connected?

Comment: you can prove it in many ways... see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169319/about-path-connected-covering-spaces/1169354#1169354